# Using SQL query in Marketing Cloud with a hidden field in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, hidden-fields

Is it possible to run a SQL query that uses a hidden field in Sales Cloud?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if the object holding this field is synchronized and this fields appears in Synchronized Data Extensions.

No, if it's not synchronized.

Another way to retrieve it if you don't want to synchronize it would be to use the [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/) AMPscript function, but that would only make sense on a CloudPage.

Comment: Thank you a lot @zuzannamj!